# Topics in algbera Herstein (section $6.4$) , question $15$:

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

This  question taken From Topics  in algbera Herstein  (section $6.4$) question $15$:

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be the field of real number  and Given set $$S =\Bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}  0 &1&0&0\\-1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&-1&0  \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}  0 &0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&-1&0&0\\-1&0&0&0  \end{bmatrix}\Bigg \}$$
>
> Find all the $A \in \mathbb{F_4}$ such that $AM= MA$ for all $M \in S$

I take $M= \begin{bmatrix}  1 &0&0&x\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1  \end{bmatrix}$ where  $x \in \mathbb{F}$

I think this must satisfied $AM= MA$

Any Hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: You need to find all solutions. Write $M=(m_{ij})$ and determine $AM$ and $MA$ in terms of the elements of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Caveat Emptor!***  In this answer, contrary to my usual habit, I have made rather 
severe adjustments to the OP's choice of notation, often using the same symbols for my own purposes.  For example, Messi fifa uses $M$ for members of the set $S$, whereas below I use $M$ for a general matrix whose form is to be found; similarly, our OP uses $A$ as I use $M$, whereas I use $A$ as an intermediate matrix variable in a sub-argument.  Neverthelss, I have defined all my terms as I introduce them, so the attentive should have no difficulty.  These things being written . . .

Set

$J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 1$

also, set

$P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 2$

then denoting the elements of $S$ by $S_J$, $S_P$, we may write them in block form in an obvious manner:

$S_J = \begin{bmatrix} J & 0 \\ 0 & J \end{bmatrix}, \tag 3$

and

$S_P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & P \\ -P & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 4$

now any matrix $M \in M_4(\Bbb R)$ may also be written in terms of $2 \times 2$ blocks:

$M = \begin{bmatrix} M_{11} & M_{12} \\ M_{21} & M_{22} \end{bmatrix}; \tag 5$

then the criterion

$S_J M = MS_J \tag 6$

becomes

$\begin{bmatrix} J & 0 \\ 0 & J \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} M_{11} & M_{12} \\ M_{21} & M_{22} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} M_{11} & M_{12} \\ M_{21} & M_{22} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} J & 0 \\ 0 & J \end{bmatrix}, \tag 7$

and

$S_PM = MS_P \tag 8$

is written

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & P \\ -P & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} M_{11} & M_{12} \\ M_{21} & M_{22} \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} M_{11} & M_{12} \\ M_{21} & M_{22} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & P \\ -P & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 9$

from (7),

$\begin{bmatrix} JM_{11} & JM_{12} \\ JM_{21} & JM_{22} \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} M_{11}J & M_{12}J \\ M_{21}J & M_{22}J \end{bmatrix}, \tag{10}$

whereas from (9):

$ \begin{bmatrix} P M_{21} & P M_{22} \\ -P M_{11} & -P M_{12} \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} -M_{12} P & M_{11} P \\ -M_{22} P & M_{21}P \end{bmatrix}; \tag{11}$

from (10) and (11) we thus obtain the following equations satisfied by the $M_{ij}$:

$JM_{ij} = M_{ij}J, \; 1 \le i, j \le 2; \tag{12}$

$PM_{11} = M_{22}P, \tag{13}$

$PM_{12} = -M_{21}P, \tag{14}$

$PM_{21} = -M_{12}P, \tag{15}$

$PM_{22} = M_{11}P; \tag{16}$

now let

$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}; \tag{17}$

then

$JA = AJ \tag{18}$

becomes

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{19}$

or

$\begin{bmatrix} c & d \\ -a & -b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -b & a \\ -d & c \end{bmatrix}, \tag{20}$

from which we infer

$d = a, \; c = -b; \tag{21}$

therefore,

$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix} = aI + bJ, \; a, b \in \Bbb R; \tag{22}$

we conclude each $M_{ij}$ is of the general form (22), though of course the parametes $a$ and $b$ will vary between them.

We next observe that (2) yields

$P^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = I, \tag{23}$

the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix; therefore, from (13),

$M_{22} = M_{22}P^2 = (M_{22}P)P = PM_{11}P, \tag{24}$

and (15),

$M_{21} = P^2 M_{21} = P(PM_{21}) = -PM_{12}P; \tag{25}$

if we set

$B = \begin{bmatrix} e & f \\ g & h \end{bmatrix}, \tag{26}$

then

$PBP = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} e & f \\ g & h \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} f & e \\ h & g \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} h & g \\ f & e \end{bmatrix}; \tag{27}$

if we now apply (27) to a matrix of the form $A$ (22) we see that

$PAP = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}. \tag{28}$

We may now summarize the structural features of matrices $M \in M_4(\Bbb R)$ which we have discovered above from (13)-(27):

***1.)*** Each matrix $M$ satisfying (6) and (8) may be expressed in the block form (5), where each $M_{ij}$, $1 \le i, j \le 2$ is a $2 \times 2$ real matrix;

$M_{ij} \in M_2(\Bbb R), \; 1 \le i, j \le n; \tag{28}$

***2.)***  Each of the $M_{ij}$ is of the form

$M_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix} = aI + bJ, \; a, b \in \Bbb R; \tag{29}$

by virtue of the fact that

$J^2 = -I, \tag{30}$

we see that each $M_{ij}$ as in (29) may be thought of as a matrix analogue of the complex number $a + bi$; in fact, the function

$\phi: \Bbb C \to M_2(\Bbb R), \; \phi(a + bi) = aI + bJ = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix} \tag{31}$

is in fact a field isomorphism from $\Bbb C$ to a subfield of the matrix ring $M_2(\Bbb R)$;

***3.)*** The operation

$M_{ij} \to PM_{ij}P \tag{32}$

gives rise to the matrix mapping

$aI + bJ  = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} = aI - bJ, \tag{33}$

and hence corresponds to complex conjugation.

***4.)*** From (12)-(16), (24)-(25) we see that $M_{11}$ and $M_{12}$ may be freely selected to be of the form $aI + bJ$, and that then the two remaining blocks $M_{21}$, $M_{22}$ of $M$ are determined by the operation (32); therefore the desired matrices satisfying (6)-(8) are of the general form

$M = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ -b & a & -d & c \\ -c & d & a & -b \\ -d & -c & b & a \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} aI + bJ & cI + dJ \\ -cI + dJ & aI - bJ \end{bmatrix}. \tag{34}$

***Finally, point***

***5.)***  Careful scrutiny of the steps leading up to (34) indicates they may effectively be reversed; thus every $M$ of the form (34) satisfies both (6) and (8).

Comment: thanks u  so much @Robert sir

Comment: My pleasure, friend.  And thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!